# gcc - linking multiple c files to a c++ file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

How do you link 2 c library files, to a c++ file?

Right now I am doing this:

```
> gcc -c file1.c (this works fine) 

> gcc -c file2.c ( this works fine)

> g++ -c myc++file.cpp (this works fine)

> g++ -o program myc++file.o file1.o file2.o
```

-> I get an error on this last one saying that their is a undefined reference to a function in myc++file.o, but that function is defined in file2.o. Something is wrong, but I just cant figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this function `static`?

Did you use `extern "C"` in `myc++file.cpp`?

if the answers is `no` and `yes`, show us some code.

(By the way, try to check using `nm` if that function is really in `file2.o`)

Comment: Technically both of you are right, thanks alot for the quick repsonse. I saw you responded first. For anyone else with this same problem, this answer is good, then also look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `extern "C"` on the function's declaration.
When C++ sees an external function, it mangles the name, to identify the parameter and return value types. When trying to link it with C code, the names don't match.
`extern "C"` tells C++ not to mangle the name, so it would successfully link with C code.