# extern "C", what is it useful for?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work)

I come across the following lines in many libraries; what are they good for? When/where is  __`cplusplus` defined?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

//...

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Answer (score 4):

`__cplusplus` is defined for C++ code. It happens sometimes that you have to mix C code, and C++ code. There can be many reasons for that, e.g. you have a driver written long ago in C that you want to use in your brand new C++0x project.

Every function type and name has a language linkage. There's a difference between C adn C++ functions, since C does not have function names overloading, a function name can serve as a unique identifier in C, but can not in C++. This is called [function mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Since you don't need to mangle the name in C, using `extern "C"` will make the compiler omit adding the parameter information for linkage.

The C++ standard explicitly states in 7.5 para 3:

> Every implementation shall provide for linkage to functions written in
>   the C programming language, "C", and linkage to C++ functions, "C++".

```
complex sqrt(complex); //C++ linkage by default
extern "C" {
    double sqrt(double);//C linkage
}
```

Comment: @SingerOffTheFall Awesome, you can put whatever C code you want inside those brackets? What is 7.5 para 3?

Comment: @saad, yes that is used to include valid C code inside of C++. 7.5 paragraph 3 is a section of the standard which I quoted.

Comment: "lets you execute C code" is just nonsense. Everything in C++ is C++. `extern "C"` is just a linkage specifier.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Do you have a link to the standard?

Comment: @saad, the standard itself can be bought [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372), and you can't get it for free officially, however, you can find one of the latest drafts which are usually available for free, and do not differ much from the final version.