# Fix LNK2019: unresolved external symbol with freeglut

Tags: c++, visual-c++, freeglut

Using [this manual](http://surflab.cise.ufl.edu/wiki/Getting_Started_with_OpenGL_in_VisualC++_2010), I tried to get freeglut OpenGL application to compile on my computer. This means I:

- Copied files from freeglut archive to MS program files folder
- Specified `freeglut.lib` in additional dependencies
- Set explicitly the freeglut.lib path in libraries folders

But all takes no effect. The C++ header files are found right, but the libraries not - so I get these errors:

```
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutMainLoop@0 referenced in function _wmain
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutSpecialFunc@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl specialKeys(int,int,int)" (?specialKeys@@YAXHHH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutDisplayFunc@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitDisplayMode@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutInitWithExit@12 referenced in function _glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK@8
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8 referenced in function _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4
1>OpenglTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutSwapBuffers@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
```

So my questions:

1. Could you guess what may be wrong? (not easy, but I cannot find this out obviously)
2. Is there some other manual google didn't find, but better than the one I used?
3. Is there some other archive I should download?

My C++ code comes [from here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cube-in-OpenGL). All functions are well found in freeglut header files. Just the libraries are missing.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a `C vs C++` linkage issue. You are compiling a `C source` code from [there](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cube-in-OpenGL) as a `C++ code` (maybe you saved it with C++ specific **extensions** and the compiler assumed it is C++).

C++ will mangle function names.  For example `__imp__glutMainLoop@0` is most probabley a call to `glutMainLoop` in your source code.

The library must have been from a C code. Hence it will have a non mangled version of the function simply as `glutMainLoop`. That's why it can not be found.

The solution is either compile your code as C code or use [extern "C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c).

EDIT: Some Links on how to deal with with C/C++ linkage issues (Moved from the comments).

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mix-c-and-cpp/
- [Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work)
- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/c-calls-cpp.html

Comment: The `extern "C"` is to be placed in the C function defenitions in the library?

Comment: For your case I think you just have to compile your code as C. Assuming you don't need any C++ features in the code. However if you need to use C++ for our own code then you need to wrap the functions you use with extern. See this on how to do it. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mix-c-and-cpp/

Comment: The first example is your case.

Comment: Your answer has given me a lot, but it showed up that all problems were caused by using x64 precompiled .dll and .lib. But I'm happy to know this about C and C++, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :). Just curious, So your code was compiled as C?

Comment: By the way, can whole included file be wrapped in extern? `extern "C"{#include "c_file.h"}` (imagine some new lines here)

Comment: Yes. But add an ifedf __cplusplus to it. So that it will compile accordingly when it is C++. like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work

Comment: And this should help you if you need more in depth. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/c-calls-cpp.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27256/discussion-between-tomas-zato-and-stardust)