# Call a C function from C++ code

Tags: c++, c, linux, extern-c

I have a C function that I would like to call from C++. I couldn't use "`extern "C" void foo()`" kind of approach because the C function failed to be compiled using g++. But it compiles fine using gcc. Any ideas how to  call the function from C++?

Comment: Could you please write some example code and `g++` error messages

Comment: @MarkGarcia C and C++ are different languages. Yes, there are things in C that don't exist in C++. I'm sick of explaining this, hence why I asked [Why shouldn't I compile C code with a C++ compiler, or write C++ code to be compilable in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247969/why-shouldnt-i-compile-c-code-with-a-c-or-write-c-code-to-be-compilable-in)

Comment: It may be the opposite. _failed to be compiled using gcc. But it compiles fine using g++_... because of the `extern "C"`

Comment: If you compile it with a C++ compiler, it's C++.  C code doesn't have to compile with a C++ compiler.  They are different languages.  Your code isn't valid C++ and therefor doesn't compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget `void valid_in_C_but_not_in_CPlusPlus(size_t size) { char variable_length_array[size]; }`

Comment: @undefined behaviour: never thought it was valid C (now I know it is C99)... and with `g++` it compiles correctly, however, clearly states as forbidden with `-pedantic`. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget Another one: `struct valid_in_C { struct but_not_in_CPlusPlus { int a; } b; int c; }; struct but_not_in_CPlusPlus d;`

Comment: My try: `void f(void *pv) { int *pi = pv; *pi = 42; }` ^^

Comment: You don't have to compile your 'C' code with `g++`. That's what `extern "C"` means. Compile it with `gcc`. Not a real question.

Comment: This should be left open, especially as it has good answers pointing out how the C (rather than C++) compiler can be used for the C code.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Compile the C code like this:

```
gcc -c -o somecode.o somecode.c
```

Then the C++ code like this:

```
g++ -c -o othercode.o othercode.cpp
```

Then link them together, with the C++ linker:

```
g++ -o yourprogram somecode.o othercode.o
```

You also have to tell the C++ compiler a C header is coming when you include the declaration for the C function. So `othercode.cpp` begins with:

```
extern "C" {
#include "somecode.h"
}
```

`somecode.h` should contain something like:

```
 #ifndef SOMECODE_H_
 #define SOMECODE_H_

 void foo();

 #endif
```

---

*(I used gcc in this example, but the principle is the same for any compiler. Build separately as C and C++, respectively, then link it together.)*

Comment: @Arne Good points. Some folks schmear some C++ in their C by wrapping the `extern "C"` in the header with [`#ifdef __cplusplus`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work).

Comment: @Arne See my answer below. unwind As you can see I'm one of them ;)

Comment: I was receiving the following error:
Error: #337: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "foo" (declared at line 1)
Now its compiling okay. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani, not without a lot more detail.

Comment: @Prof.Falken I get it, it was due to another header file that included same declaration, I just put mine above it.

Comment: @FaizanHussainRabbani - a nice way to avoid these problems is to put an include guard in your header files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: haha, perfect answer.. Thank you! I was not able to figure out, that i need to use extern "C" to the header files.. w t f ..

Answer (score 78):

Let me gather the bits and pieces from the other answers and comments, to give you an example with cleanly separated C and C++ code:

## The C Part:

**foo.h**:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo(void);

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Compile this with `gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c`.

## The C++ Part:

**bar.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
  #include "foo.h" //a C header, so wrap it in extern "C" 
}

void bar() {
  foo();
}
```

Compile this with `g++ -c -o bar.o bar.cpp`

And then link it all together:

```
g++ -o myfoobar foo.o bar.o
```

**Rationale:**
The C code should be plain C code, no `#ifdef`s for "maybe someday I'll call this from another language". If some C++ programmer calls your C functions, it's *their* problem how to do that, not yours. And if you are the C++ programmer, then the C header might not be yours and you should not change it, so the handling of unmangled function names (i.e. the `extern "C"`) belongs in your C++ code.

You might, of course, write yourself a convenience C++ header that does nothing except wrapping the C header into an `extern "C"` declaration.

Comment: Seems legit. +1 for the rationale

Comment: Finally a completely clear explanation of this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 18):

I agree with [Prof. Falken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851023/688659), but after Arne Mertz's comment I want to give a complete example (the most important part is the `#ifdef __cplusplus`):

**somecode.h**

```
#ifndef H_SOMECODE
#define H_SOMECODE

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* H_SOMECODE */
```

**somecode.c**

```
#include "somecode.h"

void foo(void)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

**othercode.hpp**

```
#ifndef HPP_OTHERCODE
#define HPP_OTHERCODE

void bar();

#endif /* HPP_OTHERCODE */
```

**othercode.cpp**

```
#include "othercode.hpp"
#include "somecode.h"

void bar()
{
    foo(); // call C function
    // ...
}
```

Then you follow Prof. Falken's instructions to compile and link.

This works because when compiling with `gcc`, the macro `__cplusplus` is not defined, so the header `somecode.h` included in `somecode.c` is like this after preprocessing:

```
void foo(void);
```

and when compiling with `g++`, then `__cplusplus` *is* defined, and so the header included in `othercode.cpp` is now like that:

```
extern "C" {

void foo(void);

}
```

Comment: thb, I don't like the `#ifdef __cplusplus` in C code. The C code is the lower level, and it should not have to bother if it might be called from C++ code some day. Imo that `#ifdef` has its use only in C++ code if you want to provide a C binding header for a library written in C++, not the other way round.

Comment: @Prof.Falken of course, but it's a define meant to be able to provide "downward" compatbility of C++ code, not for C code.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is inspired by a case where Arne's rationale was correct.  A vendor wrote a library which once supported both C and C++; however, the latest version only supported C.  The following vestigial directives left in the code were misleading:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

This cost me several hours trying to compile in C++. Simply calling C from C++ was much easier.

The ifdef  __cplusplus convention is in violation of the single responsibility principle.  A code using this convention is trying to do two things at once:

- (1) execute a function in C
  -- and --
- (2) execute the same function in C++

It's like trying to write in both American and British English at the same time. This is unnecessarily throwing an #ifdef __thequeensenglish spanner #elif __yankeeenglish wrench #else a useless tool which makes the code harder to read #endif into the code.

For simple code and small libraries the ifdef  __cplusplus convention may work; however, for complex libraries it is best to pick one language or the other and stick with it.  Supporting one of the languages will take less maintenance than trying to support both.

This is a record of the modifications I made to Arne's code to get it to compile on Ubuntu Linux.

**foo.h**:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo(void);

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
     // modified to verify the code was called
     printf("This Hello World was called in C++ and written in C\n");
}
```

**bar.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    #include "foo.h" //a C header, so wrap it in extern "C" 
}

int main() {
  foo();
  return(0);
}
```

**Makefile**

```
# -*- MakeFile -*-
# dont forget to use tabs, not spaces for indents
# to use simple copy this file in the same directory and type 'make'

myfoobar: bar.o foo.o
    g++ -o myfoobar foo.o bar.o 

bar.o: bar.cpp
    g++ -c -o bar.o bar.cpp

foo.o: foo.c
    gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
```