# How to call C DLL functions C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c, dll, c++-cli

I have looked into lot of online searches and most have examples which talk about C# with C or C++ with C# but have never come across using C DLL calling from C++ (specifically from  C++/CLI with WPF in my case).

Can someone please explain with an example how to call C DLL functions in C++. I have a C DLL which has all its functions defined as extern "C" funcName() and there is also a export functions .def file which has all the function names which need to be exported. Now having this C DLL how can I call its exported functions in a C++ code.

Thanks.

Comment: Just call the exported functions directly.  This is entirely the point of using C++/CLI.

Comment: @HansPassant Its *almost* that easy...but it is not that easy. Gotta link like you normally would. Gotta wrap your includes in exten C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so "WPF with C++" is not a language. WPF is a .NET library. C++/CLI is the language you are writing in.

Calling C dlls from C++/CLI is "pretty darn easy", depending on how the DLL was exported. You can either use the .NET libraries to do this, or the C libraries (I suggest the C libraries). There are two ways to link to a dll: implicit linking or explicit linking.

Implicit linking is much cleaner, imho. But you require access to a header file (Edit: *possibly* with declspec decorations, see BenVoigt's notes below) and a .lib file. If you have any of these, simply add the .lib file to the Additional Dependencies (right-click project->properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input) and add the header file path to the include (right-click project->properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General). Then you can include the header file (props to metacubed for mentioning this) as an extern "C" header file:

```
extern "C"
{
   #inlude "c_header.h"
}
```

(this is because C++ does name-mangling so that you can have overloading & namespaces & classes and stuff. It'll interpret your C header file as a C++ header file (and mangle all your names) if you don't use the `extern "C"`)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx

Or you can link explicitly

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/784bt7z7.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzk20sxw.aspx

But I suspect that figuring out that you're using C++/CLI, that'll tell you what to google. (Though C++ answers will work for you too).

For the .NET way, an easy trick is to look up the C# call (please note that this is also explicit linking, and thus doesn't require the .lib file and headers).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzhw3s8.aspx

Now the tricky bit is that if you're using C++/CLI and want to get your fancy managed classes into C form, you'll have to **marshal** the code. Here is a handy link to a tabel that shows you how.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120%28vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry I quickly corrected my question from C++ to C++/CLI but I guess by the time I edited, you already spotted me wrong. :-)  Thanks for your answer though, I will give a shot with your Implicit Linking solution, I was suspecting that but wanted expert advises on it. Thanks!

Comment: No declspec decorations needed.  That's the whole point of an import library, actually.

Comment: @BenVoigt As far as I know, from a *dll*, __declspec(import) is required for implicit linking. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw3za17w.aspx. Explicit linking wouldn't require it, but would require you to call LoadLibrary and do a bunch more stuff. Though you are right for a static library.

Comment: @madsciencedreams, I'm not sure how you turned "saves a thunk but slows DLL load" into "required".

Answer (score 2):

Calling a C dll function from a C++ dll is exactly the same, whether it is for WPF, C++/CLI or native C++.

1. Include the header file. See below for syntax.
2. Add the `.lib` as an import dependency to your project. Also set the linker to consume the DLL. See [Linking implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx) for all the details.
3. Make sure that the consumed DLL is present in the run-time class path when the program executes.
4. Use the function defined in the header file.

The header file include should be declared as:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "c_header.h"
}
```

That's all!

EDIT: Also, check this out: [Call a C function from C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code).

Comment: Thanks metacubed, @MadScienceDreams + others for the feedback. After getting a better understanding on what mechanism would work best between "Implicit Linking" & "Explicit Linking", I see that I will have to go for Explicit Linking, knowing that I want to link the DLL at run-time and not during compile time. I am planning to load a DLL using my WPF app and then use the exported functions from the DLL I load. But I am having a hard time in understanding how could I do that in a WPF app written in C++/CLI environment. Any further help in explaining Explicit Linking in WPF will be helpful.