# error: expected unqualified-id on extern "C"

Tags: c++, clang, extern-c

I have a cpp code in which I want to call a c function.
Both compile well to .o files, but when the clang++ is executing for compilation, I receive the following error:

```
file.cpp:74:12: error: expected unqualified-id
    extern "C"
           ^
```

The code in the cpp file is the following:

```
void parseExtern(QString str)
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
#endif
        function_in_C(str);
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

}
```

How can I avoid the error ? I can't compile the c file with clang++, I really need to use extern. Thanks.

Comment: @Mat: That's an _answer_!! Yes it's a short one but, well, it's an easy question :P

Comment: So what's the best way for me to call my C function from CPP ? Regarding QString, I can easily convert to char *.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello: Declare the function with `extern "C"`. Call it just like any other function.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello - I think ***[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16851023/645128)*** addresses your comment question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `extern "C"` linkage specification is something you attach to a function declaration. You don't put it at the call site.

In your case, you'd put the following in a header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
#endif
        void function_in_C(char const *); /* insert correct prototype */
        /* add other C function prototypes here if needed */
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Then in your C++ code, you just call it like any other function. No extra decoration required.

```
char const * data = ...;
function_in_C(data);
```

Comment: This error can also happen if you accidentally put the extern "C" declaration inside a class declaration. Solution: move it outside the class.