# c++ undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "function_name" referenced from

Tags: c++, undefined, x86-64, symbols

Yes, I know there's already several questions that go into detail about this, but I feel like my question isn't that detail-specific. Just something staring at me in the face, but I can't quite see it.

I'm compiling C and C++ files together in a Makefile. Everything seems to be running fine until I get the titular error, which pertains to the functions in CFile2.

Compilation works like this (w/ placeholder names):

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c Class.cpp
gcc -c CFile1.c
gcc -c CFile2.c
g++ main.o Class.o CFile1.o CFile2.o -lcurl
```

My Class.cpp has a Class.hpp, and my CFile1 and CFile2 both have .h files respectively. Everything is located within the same directory, and they all have the same header guard structure.

```
#ifndef
#define

//Insert function prototypes here

#endif
```

I'm also only including the CFile1.h and CFile2.h in Class.hpp. Is there something I'm missing based on this info only?

Comment: maybe look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code ...  Also, #pragma(once) (you may have to google it) is nicer than those include guards...

Comment: #pragma once works if your build environment A) uses a compiler that supports it (most seem to these days, but it fails silently if the build system does not) and B) does not use network mounted drives or symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the `extern "C"` in the c header?

If you compile c file and want to link with c++ you mast add `extern "C"`, but the c compiler doesn't recognize it so it must is the `#ifdef __cplusplus`

Add at the beginning of the header, before functions deceleration:

```
#include <stdio> // and all other includes...
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void funnction_name1(); //sample 1
int funnction_name2(char* p); //sample 2

//must close the extern "C" block
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

you can also add it before each function as follows:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C"
 #endif
 // no block for the extern "C", so it applied only for a single function
 void funnction_name(); //a sample func.
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly.