# Add library in qt linux

Tags: c++, c, qt, clion

I created a project library in Clion and got a *.a file. In qt_gui.pro I added:

```
LIBS += -L /path/to/*.a/file
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/directory/h_files
```

Also I created new .h file with:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "foo.h"
}
void qt_foo();
```

And .cpp file:

```
void qt_foo(){
    foo();
}
```

When I calling qt_foo() I getting

```
error: undefined reference to `foo'
```

foo.h in library:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void foo();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: You must also add the header, to use the code from c to c ++ check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code

Comment: @eyllanesc Do I need to add .h files to the qt project?

Comment: Use `INCLUDEPATH += /path/of/header-directory`

Comment: Try with `extern "C" {
    foo();
}`

Comment: @eyllanesc nothing changed :(

Comment: The problem is related to your [`LIBS` statement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html#library-files): `LIBS += -L/path/to/library/folder -lmylibrary`, or alternatively (not portable) `LIBS += /path/to/my/library/libmylibrary.a`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project

Comment: Note that _"undefined reference"_ is a linking error and has nothing to do with header include directories.

Comment: @m7913d yep, thanks you, but works only alternatively way (LIBS += /path/to/my/library/libmylibrary.a). What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you added `-lmylibrary`? I would expect that qt displays an error when he is not able to locate a library. Have you checked the compile output window?

Comment: @m7913d yes, qt displays "not found"

Comment: @DanielMur What is your exact library name and `LIBS` command? If the name of the library is `libMyLibrary.a`, you should write `LIBS += -lMyLibrary`, i.e. remove the `lib` prefix.

Comment: @m7913d I understand. thanks you