# Why linkage failed even when nm found the symbol?

Tags: linux, dynamic, g++

When I compile a demo `main.cpp`, it failed because `undefined reference to a_mtk_bt_service_init()`, but I have found the symbol by

`nm -D ./libmtk_bt_service_client.so|grep a_mtk_bt_service_init`,

it's output is `0000000000004098 T a_mtk_bt_service_init`,

I'm sure the compiler found the correct dynamic library by use command `aarch64-poky-linux-g++ -print-file-name=libmtk_bt_service_client.so -o main main.cpp`

This is the demo code `main.cpp`

```
void a_mtk_bt_service_init();
int main()
{
   a_mtk_bt_service_init();
   return 0;
}
```

and my compile command is

```
aarch64-poky-linux-g++ -mcpu=cortex-a72.cortex-a53+crypto -mtune=cortex-a72.cortex-a53 --sysroot=/home/sundq/code/newT9/T9-Amazon-Sdk/build/tmp/sysroots/aud8516-slc -o build/xx main.cpp -I../../include -lmtk_bt_service_client
```

Comment: `cortex-a72.cortex-a53+crypto` looks a bit unusual to me. Do you really want the `big.LITTLE system` variant? All the ARM systems I work on are little endian. What architectures does `nm` have to say about the files? Maybe try with `-march=armv8-a`. Also see [3.18.1 AArch64 Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html) in the GCC manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here [Call a C function from C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code), that is, when c++ code call a c function, we also must add `extern "C"` before the declare of c function,
so my function declare should like this

`extern "C" void a_mtk_bt_service_init();`