# ffmpeg undefined references on multiple functions

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile an application that is using ffmpeg on Ubuntu and I am running into the following errors.

```
undefined reference to `av_write_image_line2'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_transfer_data'
undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_get_hwframe_constraints'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_get_buffer'
undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_ctx_create_derived'
undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_get_cursor_image_cursor_image'
undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_query_version'
undefined reference to `avpriv_slicethread_execute'
undefined reference to `avcodec_parameters_to_context'
undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_get_cursor_image_reply'
undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_find_type_by_name'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_map'
undefined reference to `av_spherical_tile_bounds'
undefined reference to `av_malloc_array'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_transfer_get_formats'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_ctx_alloc'
undefined reference to `xcb_shape_rectangles'
undefined reference to `av_stereo3d_type_name'
undefined reference to `avpriv_slicethread_free'
undefined reference to `avpriv_slicethread_create'
undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_get_cursor_image'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_ctx_init'
undefined reference to `avpriv_register_devices'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_constraints_free'
undefined reference to `av_audio_fifo_peek_at'
undefined reference to `av_get_extended_channel_layout'
undefined reference to `av_hwframe_ctx_create_derived'
undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_query_version_reply'
undefined reference to `av_mallocz_array'
undefined reference to `av_read_image_line2'
```

The version of ffmpeg I have:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
configuration: --enable-pic --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm'
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
```

In my makefile I have added -lavutil -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lswresample -lswscale to my link step.

What am I doing wrong?  Are these deprecated in the version of ffmpeg I have?

Comment: hi! can you please include your makefile as well?

Answer (score 2):

The ffmpeg headers are pure C headers.  So if you're trying to use them in a C++ application, you'll need to surround the include statement with the `extern "C"` declaration.  For example:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```

If it's not clear what that declaration is doing, there are good explanations [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code).

Answer (score 0):

it could be due to your compiler unable to find the right place of the required components. if you know their whereabouts, you may try to use "symlink" to link it to the directory/place where your compiler is looking at.

eg:

ln -s /path/of/the/library /path/you/want/it/to/be/found