# How to define extern "C" functions in my c++ file?

Tags: android, c++

I have a .so library that I want to link with C++ code. There's a function called `add` on the .so file that respect C interface (its declared as extern "C"). I don t have the .h file so I did something like this but on Android:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int add(int, int);
//int add(int, int);

int main()
{
  std::cout << add(1,1) << std::endl;
}
```

If I use `extern "C" int add(int, int);` I get compilation error about the function `add` not being declared. If I use `int add(int, int);` it compiles but linking fails (but it could be for other reasons).

Which is the right way to define an extern C functin from a .so?

Comment: Can you include the exact error message?  Also, which compiler?

Comment: Did you check for some details in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code