# Calling C function from C++ with same name

Tags: c++, c

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code) but I do not know what to do if I have the two functions in C++ and C have the same name. The C function is already guarded with if `#ifdef __cplusplus` in the header file.
so I have in .cpp file

```
foo (int a, int b)
{
//calling from C
foo (int a, int b, int c)
}
```

Cheader.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo(int a,int b, int c);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

file.c

```
#include "Cheader.h"

void foo(int a,int b, int c)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

C++ header

```
Cplusplusheader.hpp

void foo(int a, int b);
```

C++

```
CplusPlus.cpp

#include "Cplusplus.hpp"
#include "Cheader.h"

void foo(int a, int b)
{
    foo(a,b,c); // call C function
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please further explain how you are calling the C function from C++ and how the project is structured?

Comment: The same as in the referenced answers

Comment: @HazemAbaza that is not helpful info

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I updated the question

Comment: What the question is ? Check [C++ namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)

Comment: Hopefully an obvious note, but `foo(int a, int b, int c)` isn't a call to a function: you probably meant something like `foo(a, b, 100);` or whatever. Please update your code to the actual code you are having issues with so we can try it as well.

Comment: @N.Shead , Sorry . I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just made an example to test this out and you'd call it as any other function. The compiler seems to understand that the C foo is just an overload of your C++ foo. Here's an example:

main.cpp

```cpp
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

//c++ foo
void foo(int num1, int num2)
{
    foo(num1);
    foo(num2);
    std::cout << "Sum: " << num1 + num2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```c
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

//c foo
void foo(int number);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

source.c

```c
//source.c

#include "header.h"

//c foo
void foo(int number)
{
    printf("The number is: %i\n", number);
}
```

Output:

```
The number is: 10
The number is: 10
Sum: 20
```