# Invoking an application in C from a winforms

Tags: c++, c, winforms

I have developed an application in C using Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 10 platform. When starting up the application in the console in main(), the user is first asked to specify encode or decode, then is asked to input a number of values, including input and output filenames. The filenames together with these numerical values are then passed to one of two function to encode or decode, then the function specified calls a number of other functions to perform all the operations, before returning the output to the console as a log file, and writing the output files.

My intention is that instead of passing the input values and filenames from the console, they are passed from a GUI to my application in C, then some of the output is written back to the console, including any error messages, together with the output files being written, and a log in the console.

I have only just started looking at developing GUIs in C++, and from some online tutorials, it appears that the simplest option is to use winforms. Accordingly I tried out an example to create a simple winform using C++ in Visual Studio. By default 2 files are created, MainForm.cpp, which has a few lines of created boiler-plate code, and MainForm.h, which contains the code for handling the widgets, which you edit or modify with the MainForm design.

My question is: How do you invoke code in C from MainForm.h, or from MainForm.c? I know about name mangling, so either I have to call up a short main function in C++, then from there call the code in C, or skip that step and call the code in C directly after dealing with the name mangling in MainForm.h or MainForm.cpp. Some of the code in C will have to be changed, but most of it can hopefully be left unchanged.

I have seen a number of related questions, but so far as I can see, none involving calling C from winforms so some advice is most appreciated.

Comment: No mention of `extern "C"` in your research? Or `#ifdef __cplusplus ... stuff ... #endif`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code

Comment: I mentioned name mangling, so I know about extern "C", perhaps I should have mentioned this, and know that it has to be placed before invoking the code in C. One of these issues is whether it is placed in MainForm.h, in MainForm.cpp, or in a very short section of code in C++ that is called from one of these files, and uses extern "C" when invoking my application in C.