# How to prevent C++ name mangling in a Cocoa framework

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++, name-mangling

I created a function in a Cocoa Framework that I want to export. This function is implement in ObjectiveC++, and the name mangling of C++ is driving me nuts.

I already declared the function within an extern "C" block, to no avail.

This is my header file in the framework:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

extern "C"{
    void display(NSString *text);
}

@interface Display : NSObject

@end
```

and this is the .mm file:

```
#import "Display.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void display(NSString *text){
    cout << [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] << endl;
}

@implementation Display


@end
```

It compiles fine, without any errors.

On the client side, I added the framework, imported the exposed header and tried to call the function:

```
display(@"Hola");
```

Here I get a warning complaining that **"implicit declaration of function display is invalid in C99"**.

To add insult to injury, in the exposed header file I get an error (that doesn't show up in the framework project), in the extern "C" line:

**"expected identifier or ("**

What else is necessary to get this going?

Comment: What errors or problems are you seeing?

Comment: I just added the full code and errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `extern "C"` to the function implementation as well as the declaration. If the implementation of the function is in a `.mm` (Objective-C++) file, it will be compiled as Objective-C++, with name mangling. It doesn't matter that you happen to have an `extern "C"` declaration for a function with the same name. They are still seen as two different things.

So wrap your implementation in `extern "C"` as well to remove the name mangling for the function implementation:

```
extern "C" void display(NSString *text) {

}
```

Or:

```
extern "C" {
    void display(NSString *text) {

    }
}
```

Also, if you want your header to be usable by C code, you will need to add an `#ifdef` to only use `extern` when compiling as C++. `extern` is not a valid keyword in C:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif
void display(NSString *text);
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

See [Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work) for more information.