# Linking problems with g++, but not with cc

Tags: c++, c, linker

I'm using 64-bit CentOS version of Linux.  I'm trying to create and use a static library (libUtility.a) in my C and C++ programs.  I can compile the library with C, and produce the libUtility.a file with ar.  Then I try to link it into my program.  Everything works when I use the C compiler

```
cc myprog.c -o myprog -I/usr/local/include -L/LocationOfMyLib -lUtility
```

However, when I use the g++ compiler, I receive the errors.

```
g++ myprog.c -o myprog -I/usr/local/include -L/LocationOfMyLib -lUtility
myprog.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
/tmp/cckIN1Yk.o: In function `main':
myprog.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `Utility_HiWorld(char*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have moderate experience in C and C++, but no experience creating my own
libraries.  This library only has one subroutine named Utility_HiWorld().  And myprog.c only calls that one subroutine.  What am I doing wrong in here?

NEW: Okay, I definitely didn't use 'extern "C"'.  I didn't even know what that was.  That solved it.

Comment: The fact that the C++ compiler is able to tell you the type of the function argument **at link time** should alarm you.

Comment: Missing `extern "C"` in the header files of your library?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you compile your C program with a C++ compiler, it may or may not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that you are failed to tell your C++ compiler that the external function is written in C.

Since you want to use the library from C and C++ you need to do something like this in your libraries header file.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void Utility_HiWorld(char*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`__cplusplus` is only defined for a C++ programs, so a C++ program will see `extern "C" { ... }` which is what it needs to tell it that `Utility_HiWorld` is a C function.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work) for more details.

Just a guess, post some code if you think the problem is something else.