# Linking C compiled static library to C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I tried to link a static library (compiled with gcc) to a c++ program and I got 'undefined reference'. I used gcc and g++ version 4.6.3 on a ubuntu 12.04 server machine. For example, here is the simple library file for factorial method:

**mylib.h**

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_H_
#define __MYLIB_H_

int factorial(int n);

#endif
```

**mylib.c**

```
#include "mylib.h"

int factorial(int n)
{
    return ((n>=1)?(n*factorial(n-1)):1);
}
```

I created object for this mylib.c using gcc:

```
gcc -o mylib.o -c mylib.c
```

Again the static library was created from the object file using AR utility:

```
ar -cvq libfact.a mylib.o
```

I tested this library with a C program (test.c) and C++ program (test.cpp)

Both C and C++ program have the same body:

```
#include "mylib.h"
int main()
{
    int fact = factorial(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming static library libfact.a is available in /home/test directory, I compiled my C program without any issues:

```
gcc test.c -L/home/test -lfact
```

However while testing C++ program, it threw a link error:

```
g++ test.cpp -L/home/test -lfact

test.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `factorial(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I even tried adding extern command in test.cpp:

```
extern int factorial(int n) //added just before the main () function
```

Still the same error.

- Can someone tell me what I am wrong here?
- Is there anything I missed while creating the static library?
- Do I have to add anything in my `test.cpp` to make it work?

Comment: When I see SO questions with no upvote, along with a 7-upvoted answer, I fully understand how foolish humanity is. How can the answer be relevant if the question is not? Come on!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't told your C++ program that factorial is written in C. You need to change your test.h header file. Like this

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_H_
#define __MYLIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int factorial(int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Now your header file should work for both C and C++ programs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work) for details.

BTW names containing a double underscore are reserved for the compliler (so are names starting with an underscore and a capital letter) so `#ifndef __MYLIB_H_` is illegal strictly speaking. I would change to `#ifndef MYLIB_H #define MYLIB_H`

Comment: Yes it works like charm with this. Thanks for the link. Thanks for adding info about double underscore.

Comment: great explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is absolutely correct, I thought I'd just add an observation. Some editors have trouble with the open / close brace, and will indent the entire `extern "C"` scope in the header. If `mylib.h` is a key header for a library, you might consider:

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
#define _MYLIB_INIT_DECL extern "C" {
#define _MYLIB_FINI_DECL }
#else
#define _MYLIB_INIT_DECL
#define _MYLIB_FINI_DECL
#endif
```

All other headers in `mylib` library, e.g., `mylib_aux.h`, can be of the form:

```
#ifndef _MYLIB_AUX_H
#define _MYLIB_AUX_H

#include <mylib.h>

_MYLIB_INIT_DECL

... header content ...

_MYLIB_FINI_DECL

#endif /* _MYLIB_AUX_H */
```

Obviously, the names I'm using are arbitrary, but for multiple library headers, this approach has been useful to me.