# In ref : Linking C compiled static library to C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Stackoverflow won't let me comment because I am a newbie.

Borrowing the title from the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063975/linking-c-compiled-static-library-to-c-program), the accepted solution says that you have to modify the C header file using `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `extern "C"`.
I have the exact same question but I have been provided a C library containing over 100 `.h` C header files and `.c` C program files and now I have to use a C++ library so my `main()` will be in C++.

So do I now have to add those modifications to each one of those C header files or is there some other approach? My `main()` is in a `.cpp` file which will use functions from this C library.

**EDIT**
This question has been resolved. I wish for this question to be closed or removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to modify any headers. What is necessary is to wrap all C declarations with `extern C {}`. You can do this just as well in you `cpp` file:

```
extern "C" {
#include "some_c_header.h"
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "This is C++ code\n";
}
```

It might be useful to create a header file which simply includes C headers with C linkage:

```
// c_header.hpp
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 

#include "c_header_1.h"
#include "c_header_2.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// main.cpp
#include "c_header.hpp" // extern "C" {} already handled for you
```

Answer (score 1):

Only those declarations of C functions and objects that are accessed by C++ components need to declared with C linkage, and only *to* the C++ components.  Presumably, your new C++ library accesses very little, if anything, from the existing C code, so the primary concern would be whatever is accessed (directly) by `main()`.  Those functions must be declared (to `main`) with C linkage.  If that turns out to be a significant number of things then you could consider refactoring to make it fewer.

Moreover, no, you do not need to modify existing header files.  The C++ files that reference your C library, and that therefore include some of its headers, can wrap the relevant `#include` statements an an `extern "C"` block to take care of the issue.