# Linking error c and c++ (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

## abc.c file

```
#include "abc.h"
int abc()
{
    return 10;
}
```

## abc.h file

```
int abc();
```

## mymain.cpp file

```
#include "abc.h"
int main()
{
    abc();
    return  0;
}
```

## Makefile

```
CC=gcc -O2 
CP=g++

mymain: mymain.o abc.o
    $(CP) -o mymain mymain.o abc.o

mymain.o: mymain.cpp abc.h
    $(CP) -c mymain.cpp abc.h

abc.o: abc.c abc.h
    $(CC) -c abc.c abc.h

clean:  
    $(RM) *.o mymain
```

## output

```
g++ -c mymain.cpp abc.h
gcc -O2  -c abc.c abc.h
g++ -o mymain mymain.o abc.o
mymain.o: In function `main':
mymain.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `abc()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mymain] Error 1
```

Why abc() is undefined reference ??

## UPDATE

## new abc.h

```
extern "C" {
    int abc();
}
```

## error

```
g++ -c mymain.cpp abc.h
gcc -O2  -c abc.c abc.h
In file included from abc.c:1:0:
abc.h:1:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
 extern "C" {
        ^
abc.h:1:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
 extern "C" {
        ^
make: *** [abc.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Don't pass `abc.h` to the compiler. Header files are processed when they're `#include`ed by `.c` or `.cpp` files.

Comment: Also, `CP` is a really bad name for this.  Most people will think you're trying to copy a file.  The default variable name in make for C++ compiler is `CXX` (and `CXXFLAGS` for C++ compiler-specific flags).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to link a C function into a C++ object, without telling the compiler this is what you're doing.

If your header file (abc.h) looked like this:

```
extern "C" {
    int abc();
}
```

it would work (when included into a C++ source... but would break when included into a C source).

You can enclose the `extern "C" {` and its trailing `}` within macros as shown in [Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work) in order to be suitable for both C and C++ inclusion.

Note that `$(CP) -c mymain.cpp abc.h` in your makefile does not make sense -- you don't want to specify the header on your compiler command line. This goes for both instances of that pattern.

Comment: @shantanu You need to conditionally exclude it when compiling the .c file because the C compiler doesn't know about `extern "C"`

Comment: I got it. It's makefile. I need to remove abc.h from $(CP) -c mymain.cpp