# Swift typedef struct from header leads undefined symbols error

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, i386

I have TimeSlot.h file where specified some code:

```
typedef struct TimeSlot
{
  uint32_t val;
} TimeSlot;


int TimeSlotMinutes(TimeSlot val);

TimeSlot TimeSlotSetMinutes(TimeSlot val, int v);
```

In .swift file I want to use this struct:

```
func setTime(minutes: Int32)
{
  var timeSlot = TimeSlot()
  timeSlot = TimeSlotSetMinutes(timeSlot, minutes)

  device.setTimeSlot(timeSlot)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_TimeSlotSetMinutes", referenced from:
AppName.Service. setTime (minutes : Swift.Int32) -> () in Service.o
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: The typedef is not the problem, but the TimeSlotSetMinutes  function. There must be a .c file (or c++ file) with the *implementation* of that function, and that must be added to the target as well.

Comment: @MartinR I have that file .mm and it's in compile sources already

Comment: @MartinR, I've searched trough the project and there are only few places where Xcode found TimeSlot. It's in Device.h and Device.mm and Device.mm it's in target membership and in compile sources. Not sure what cause that error.

Comment: Then C++ name mangling *could* be the problem, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882780/extern-function-with-macro for a similar issue.

Comment: @MartinR, cool works! thanks, like a magic!) I mean about enforcing.

Comment: @MartinR, can be an answer I guess