# How to remove surrounding characters around a symbol in a shared library?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, shared-libraries, name-mangling

I compiled a library with `g++` and I want to link against it with `gcc`.
Problem is I get an error while linking against it:

> undefined reference to 'functionName`

*(functionName is the function name in the library)*

although the function exists in the symbols list and I specify the path to `gcc` while linking.

It happens because the function appears in the list with surrounding characters (I think this is for overriding?):

`Z12functionNameiSt9__va_list`

I know that to remove these characters I should surround the function declaration with `extern "C"`. And I did that:

```
//header.hpp
extern "C" int functionName(int argc, ...);
```

But the surrounding characters still appear around the function name in the symbols list. And that's why `gcc` can't find it.

I'm cross compiling for linux arm yokto with `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` and `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++` on Ubuntu desktop 16.

Why aren't the surrounding characters being removed and how can I remove them? I will never override this function so if these are really for overriding then I don't need them.

---

**edit:**

Solved. The function signature in its declaration was different from the signature in its definition... So the `extern` keyword was for nothing.

```
int functionName(int argc, ...); //declaration
int functionName(int argc, va_list args) //definition
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot a `#include <stdarg.h>`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - It's included

Answer (score 2):

Those characters are name mangling. They encode the function signature so C++ overloading can work correctly (eg. `int foo(int)` and `int foo(float)` are different symbols).

If your API is C, you need to fix the library to not have the mangling. Build it as C or add `extern "C"` in its code. If your API is meant to be C++, remove the `extern "C"` from your header.

If the mangled names don't match (different mangling), then you probably have an ABI compatibility problem. In that case, trying to fix the link problem is the wrong solution. You need to make sure you build your code with the same ABI as the library instead.

The `c++filt` tool should be able to decode the mangled symbol into a signature. That can be useful to figure out what the difference is about.

Given you built the library with `g++` and are trying to link with `gcc`, it's likely you want a C API and rebuilding the library with the `extern "C"` in place is what you need.

Comment: The API is c (no classes) but the function uses c++ libraries. I added `extern "C"` to the header (see post) but it's not deleting the surrounding characters. Might it be because the function signature has an ellipsis (`...`)?

Comment: @AlaaM. No, it works fine with ellipsis. Did you rebuild the library with the `extern "C"` present? I understood from your post that the linker looks for `functionName` but the library contains `Z12functionNameiSt9__va_list`, which means the problem is with the library. Also make sure the library is actually including the header and not simply defining the function without any `extern "C"`.

Comment: As I said in the post, I know that the problem is in the library. The problem is that it still contains the surrounding characters

Comment: @AlaaM. sorry it wasn't clear if you had rebuilt the lib. In that case I'd suggest reducing the problem complexity: start with g++ on a single file containing an empty `extern "C"` function and see if that still exports with name mangling. I've seen a few very weird problems explained by compiling the wrong code in my career (ie. an old copy of the header without `extern "C"` in it).

Answer (score 0):

The "surrounding characters" are actually for [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). So better speak of *mangled names*.

You probably should add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

near the start of your (public) header file (that you'll better code in the common subset of C and C++), and the matching

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}; // end of extern "C"
#endif
```

near its end. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3789340/841108).

You should wrap all your public header (and perhaps standard C headers included by it) with such things (not only individual functions).

You could compile with `gcc -H` to list the included headers or `g++ -C -E` to get the preprocessed form (and examine it).

Comment: I don't understand how is that different of what I mentioned I did? I already added `extern "C"` .