# invalid conversion in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Context:

I have a piece of code that compiles and runs fine when compiled as C, and I am trying to port it to C++ to be able to use it in future C++ programs.

I'm using this structure data type in my program.

```
 typedef struct MessageDigest{
      int32_t digestLen;
      void* ctx;
      int (*Init)(void* c);
      int (*update)(void* c, const void* data, size_t len);
      int (*Final)(uint8_t* md, void* c);
   }MessageDigest;
```

In my main function I'm affecting the structure's identifiers:

```
    MessageDigest* newMD;
    /*Other code*/
    newMd->Init=&SHA1_Init; //The problem is here
```

I get this error :

```
 invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(SHA_CTX*) {aka int (*)
 (SHAstate_st*)}’ to ‘int (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

I tried with `static_cast<>` but it's not working

Comment: Show the definition of `SHA1_Init`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The message is self-explanatory. `int (*)(SHA_CTX*)` is not the same as `int (*)(void*)` and you cannot assign one to the other.

Comment: Gotta ask... why are you using function pointers like that in C++? Is it related to some legacy C library or something?

Comment: @n.m. Actually it's working in C but I want it in C++, when I changed the compiler from gcc to g++ the only error I got is this conversion.
@David it's defined in openssl/sha.h :  `int SHA1_Init(SHA_CTX *c);` I found the declaration here https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Sha(3)

Comment: @hyde it is perfectly fine to use function pointers, even in Cpp...

Comment: @n.m. s comment is correct. You have different function signatures, one taking a pointer to SHA_CTX, another a pointer to void.

Comment: @MABVT Doing type-unsafe things (those void pointer arguments) is never "fine" in modern C++. It may be "best" or at least "less bad than alternatives" in some situations, but I'd never call it "fine".

Comment: From a language implementation point of view it is perfectly fine to use it in CPP, that is all I said. That it is neither considered "modern" nor type-safe is written on another piece of paper. The "auto" keyword is also modern, it is type-safe, and still I consider it bad as it reduces the awareness of the modern cpp coder by leaving "all type deduction to the compiler" and giving a sh** on what is effectively be done. Proper use of the void* requires the developer to know what he's doing at least. But that's philosophical :D @hyde

Comment: Anyway, porting C to C++ should not be simply trying to compile C as C++...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is clear about the problem. You declare

```
int  SHA1_Init(SHAstate_st*);
```

As its parameter is declared to be a `SHAstate_st*`, is it not compatible with the function pointer declaration which expects the parameter to be a `void *`.

You have 2 ways here. The short one is to use `reinterpret_cast`. As we know that for any current compiler, a pointer to void or to struct is a mere address, it should work but IMHO it invokes Undefined Behaviour with a strict reading of standard:

```
newMd->Init=reinterpret_cast<int (*)(void *)(&SHA1_Init); // should work but not really standard compliant
```

The correct one is to wrap `SHA1_Init`.

```
int SHA1_Init_void(void *p) {
    return SHA1_Init(static_cast<SHAstate_st *>(p));
}
```

You can then correcly use it:

```
newMd->Init = &SHA1_init_void;
```

---

But anyway, you are taking it the wrong way: you are essentialy trying to compile C code in C++ which often leads to many little errors like this one. They are indeed different languages, and have particular semantics on corner cases. And it generally leads to poor code not using all the power of C++ language, mainly type safety guarantee at compile time.

Typically, having pointer to functions taking `void *` parameters in a C structure could often be better expressed by method overriding in C++. It will certainly involve more initial work, but IMHO you should considere *rewriting* the higher level of your code in modern C++ (with classes, constructors, methods and derivation, optionaly templates) and calling lower level C functions. You will get more maintainable code and have a gain in the future. Mixing C and C++ translation units in one single project is perfectly fine, and you just have to enclose the C related include files in `extern "C" { ... }` blocks from your C++ source files. The common usage is to put that directly in the `.h` files protected with a `#ifdef __cplusplus` and is demonstrated in this other SO question: [Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3789340/3545273)