# undefined reference to `function()' while putting C++ code inside C

Tags: c++, c, linker, precompiled-headers

I kinda have the inverse problem as described here:
[Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work)

The whole app is in C code and now I need to add some C++ functions there.
But while doing it I get this error:

```
/tmp/cczmWtaT.o: In function `aocl_utils::_checkError(int, char const*, int, char const*, ...)':
/home/harp/host/../common/src/AOCLUtils/opencl.cpp:245: undefined reference to `cleanup()'
/tmp/ccrmKQaT.o: In function `main':
/home/harp/host/src/main.c:165: undefined reference to `harp_setup()'
/tmp/ccGKataf.o: In function `solver_propagate(solver_t*)':
/home/harp/host/src/solver.c:751: undefined reference to `launch_kernel()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

<C code>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

But it shows the same error.

What I'm doing is including a C++ header in a C file with the extern functions that I need.

Example:

solver.c

```
#include "HarpBuffers.h"
...
```

HarpBuffers.h

```
extern void harp_setup();
extern void setup_buffers(cl_int a, cl_int b, int **h_clause, unsigned int **h_assigns, int **h_target);

extern void launch_kernel();
extern void cleanup();
```

Comment: Did you remember to do `extern "C"` in *both* the header file and the source file?

Comment: If you code allows it, the simplest solution may be to compile everything as C++ code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, both in headers and source file. The problem is that I need to call C++ functions inside the C code.

Comment: @IlyaPopov yes, but then I get that error.

Comment: You only show this .h file getting included in the C source code.  Where extern "C" does not do anything useful.  It must be included in the C++ code as well, forgetting to do this produces this linker error.

Comment: @HansPassant you're saying that all the code should be inside extern "C"? Please, clarify.

Comment: No.  Your C++ functions must be declared extern "C".  In the C++ code.  Since you did not post your C++ code, and did not know that it was important that you did, it is the most likely place you got this wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function declarations should be inside an `extern "C"` block, and they must be seen by the C++ compiler before it encounters the functions' definitions.

(The `extern "C"` is what makes the C++ compiler not mangle the names of functions.
The `#ifdef __cplusplus` makes code invisible to a C compiler.)

Like this:

HarpBuffers.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void harp_setup();
void setup_buffers(cl_int a, cl_int b, int **h_clause, unsigned int **h_assigns, int **h_target);

void launch_kernel();
void cleanup();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

(Functions have external linkage by default; there's no need to add clutter in the header.)

solver.c:

```
#include "HarpBuffers.h"
/* Use functions */
```

HarpBuffers.cpp:

```
#include "HarpBuffers.h"
// Define functions
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I think there's a misunderstading, the harp_setup, launch_kernel, setup_buffers and cleanup are all functions that use C++ code. To clarify, the app is already written in C, and I must use C++. What do I need however is to put C++ code inside one of that app functions.

Comment: @testin3r: The misunderstanding is yours. No matter what language you intended to write in, the moment you compile your code with a C compiler, _it is C code_. You cannot "put C++ code" in a C source file. All these `#ifdef` and `extern` tricks are just for making it easier to move the same file between being C++ and being C. If you want actual C++ code (code that would not be valid in C) into a C source file, you are out of luck. If you just want to port a function that would be logically valid in both languages, then molbdnilo has shown you how to do that.

Comment: @testin3r You're being very unclear. Are the "harp functions" implemented in C++ and intended to be called from C, or do you want to implement them in C but call C++ from them?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you are adding C++ codes inside C codes but `extern "C"` is to add `C` codes inside a `C++` application, so that code declared inside that section should not be considered for name mangling to avoid linking error. So declaring extern "C" does not mean anything for a C compiler. Also in your code you have preprocessor directive like `#ifdef __cplusplus` this preprocessor directive will only considered by a `C++` compiler but not a `C` compiler. Hence your `C` compiler will simply ignore that section and `extern "C"` declaration will not be added in the code. Therefore that declaration does not mean anything for a `C` compiler. It has meaning only for a `C++` compiler as a `C++` compiler will add that section of codes declared under preprocessor directive `#ifdef __cplusplus` into the `C++` codes during compilation. Please read properly what preprocessor directive means and how compiler do with these directive during compilation. Also read compilation steps. You need to declare that directives for a `C++` compiler when you add `C` codes in `C++` codes. Now you have only one option, you have to compile entire codes by a `C++` compiler instead of a `C` compiler.