# How to call a function defined in shared library (cross-compiled on linux) in Android App?

Tags: android, c++, linux, java-native-interface, cross-compiling

I am developing an android app where I have to use a shared library (cross-compiled on linux system using NDK toolchain).

Below are the steps I followed:

1. I am using the '[hello-libs ndk sample](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/hello-libs)'.
2. The shared library name is `libsum.so`, where I have two function definitions:

```
int sum(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
```

1. I have copied `libsum.so` file to the android app under path `//hello-libs/app/libs/arm64-v8a` and called `sum(10, 20)` in `//hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/hello-libs.cpp` file.
2. Updated the `CMakeLists.txt` file to add shared library while compiling. Updated `CMakeLists.txt` file below:

```
...
...
# configure import libs
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../distribution)
...
...
add_library(lib_sum SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_sum PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/sum/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libsum.so)

# build application's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

add_library(hello-libs SHARED
            hello-libs.cpp)

target_include_directories(hello-libs PRIVATE
                           ${distribution_DIR}/gmath/include
                           ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/include
                           ${distribution_DIR}/sum/include)

target_link_libraries(hello-libs
                      android
                      lib_gmath
                      lib_gperf
                      lib_sum
                      log)
```

`main.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b); 
int sub(int a, int b);
```

But I am getting the below error:

`ld: error: undefined symbol: sum(int, int)`

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: How did you update the `CMakeLists.txt` file? How do you link with the library?

Comment: Updated the post with the changes in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Please run `nm -D libsum.so`. Which symbols does it export? Also, please show the header file that you're including in hello-libs.cpp (the one containing the declarations of `sum` and `sub`).

Comment: Output of `num -D libsum.so` is below:


`0000000000002000 A __bss_end__`
`0000000000002000 A _bss_end__`
`0000000000002000 A __bss_start`
`0000000000002000 A __bss_start__`
`                 U __cxa_atexit`
`                 U __cxa_finalize`
`0000000000002000 A _edata`
`0000000000002000 A _end`
`0000000000002000 A __end__`
`0000000000000650 T main`
`                 U printf`
`                 U __register_atfork`
`00000000000005fc T sub`
`00000000000005a8 T sum`

Updated the post with header file.

Comment: Ok, so your `libsum` is written in C, not C++? Since `hello-libs` is written in C++ you might need to edit `main.h` a bit so that the linker will look for unmangled symbol names in `libsum`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have updated the main.h file as per the link shared above. Now, the app is building but failing at runtime. The error is defined below:
`
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hellolibs, PID: 10035
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/sum/lib/arm64-v8a/libsum.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~PD60oCgkuKRbLUiB-Rj5Ig==/com.example.hellolibs-WFpgY4kNXeJmCEaiaFQrkg==/lib/arm64/libhello-libs.so in namespace classloader-namespace
`

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, you might want to add the visibility flag to the functions by using the JNIEXPORT macro, which expands to **attribute**((visibility("default"))):

`extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_MyActivity_sum(JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObject, jint a, jint b) {
return a + b;
}
} // extern C`