Import C single header library in C++
I want to include an C single header library into my C++ code. The C header library has C++-incompatible code. How would one achieve this?
main.cc:
extern "C" {
  #include "single_header.h"
}

int main() {}

single_header.h:
#include <stdlib.h>
void f() {
  int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  free(p);
}

If I compile it with g++, I get the error that it is invalid C++ code, since the extern "C" is only about the function mangling.
$ g++ main.cc
In file included from main.cc:2:
single_header.h: In function ‘void f()’:
single_header.h:3:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
    3 |   int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |
      |                  void*

What would be the proper pattern to achive this?

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work

If the bad code is in the header file then you are going to need to make a wrapper where you compile the header file as a c source file and then have a C++ header file that has all of the function signatures.  Then you should be able to link your object files to the library object file

@NathanOliver how would that be done? Just creating an own object file with gcc, writing an header file without the functions to include in main.cc and then link it manually with the C obj?

put all the function prototype in a new header file, make the header file itself a .c file so it becomes your source file, then you should be able to include your new header file in both the .c file and your C++ source file.  Then you should be able to compile the C file to an object file and the C++ source to an object file and then link those together.  Basically convert the header only library into a standard header file and object file library.  That isolates the C code to the C compiler and the C++ code just sees that there are functions that can be called.

Is this a header you control or an import from elsewhere>? Why does it have a an external non-inline function definition in it?

Report it as a bug to the library developers. Keeping C libraries compatible with C++ is usually desired.


Do not define functions in header files. Place there only functions prototypes
extern "C" only says that the names should not mangled, it does not force the compiler to compile that part as C code.

single_header.h:
#ifndef S_H
#define S_H
extern "C" {
void f();
}
#endif

single_c_file.c:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "single_header.h"

void f() {
  int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  free(p);
}

Compile this file as C, not C++.
Link everything together.

Alternatively, who owns the C file? Because if it's yours to work with, change it to be compatible with both C and C++. This would generally be my preferred approach if I would ever need to use C again. Also, if you want keep code in the "header" (which I would not recommend doing), surround it with a macro so you can include the code once with the macro enabled (like in your main.cpp file), and include it in other files with the macro turned off.

The compiler says invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’.
What about try this one.
single_header.h
#include <stdlib.h>
void f() {
  int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  free(p);
}



This makes it compile as C++, but it is now instead bad style C code (using a cast where none is needed).
